# C#: how to connect to sql server 2008 express from another lan computer and windows authentication?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a SQL Server installed in a windows XP professional. If I run the application in the local computer, I can access to the database, but if I run the application in another computer that is in the same lan, I get the underlaying provider filed error.

I have the SQL Server browser started, I have enabled the TCP/IP protocols and I try to create a new user int my windows XP with the same name and password that the user of the other computer (use Windows 7) and create a new login.

In my connection string is the following:

```
<add name="myConnection" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.myModel.csdl|res://*/Model.myModel.ssdl|res://*/Model.myModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=192.168.1.5\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=myDataBase;integrated security=true;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

I have installed IIS 6.1, but I don't know how to configure, and I don't know if this can be a solution.

I would like to use windows authentication. is it possible if I have installed sql server 2008 express in Windows xp?

EDIT 01:

I try disabling the firewall and the problem is not resolved.

Comment: could you post the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open your firewall for incoming TCP connection to port 1433

IIS has nothing to do with sql server you can uninstall if you don't need  it.

Yes you can install sql express 2008 on xp because you did!

> Sql express 2008 Supported operating systems:
>
> Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2, Windows Server 2008, Windows
> Vista, Windows Vista Service Pack 1, Windows XP Service Pack 2,
> Windows XP Service Pack 3